# Why `/proc` file system should be mounted when re-install GRUB from `chroot`?

Tags: mount, grub, grub2, chroot, proc

Currently, the MBR on my machine is corrupted, so I decide to re-install GRUB from a liveCD and with `chroot`. From [this tutorial](http://zeldor.biz/2010/12/install-grub-from-chroot/), I can complete the re-installation. However, I'm not clear about the reason why I should mount `/proc` on the new root environment. (For `/dev` and `/sys` I think it is because some files should be referred.) Is the same reason for `/proc`, which files on `/proc` are required when re-installing GRUB?

Thanks and Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc` is a virtual file system that contains pretty specific information regarding the system, stuff like environmental variables and hardware setup.  So it is required for kernel specific information during `chroot` use (for example, `lsmod` is closely tied with `/proc/modules`).

> Gentoo gives  a very minimal summary in their [handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=6)

```
To make sure that the new environment works properly, 
we need to make certain file systems available there as well.

Mount the /proc filesystem on /mnt/gentoo/proc to allow 
the installation to use the kernel-provided information 
within the chrooted environment, …
```

It's mostly system information, so it likely provides that GRUB may need in the process, such as things in `/proc/sys`, which provides for scripts to be run on boot (may be involved with GRUB, I am not sure there).

If you want to get really in-depth with what `/proc` does and contains, perhaps [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) will be a good read.